IllegalArgumentException when processing shapefile with worldwind using executor service
I am using NASA worldwind library to process a shapefile. When my code is single threaded all works fine.
But when I add parallel processing with executor service to speed up things, I start getting error.
Code is:
try {
       Shapefile shapefile = new Shapefile(shpFileStream, shxFileStream, dbfFileStream, prjFileStream);
       
       List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
       List<ShapefileRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
       while (shapefile.hasNext()) { // iterate shapefile records
            ShapefileRecord record = shapefile.nextRecord();
            records.add(record);
            if(records.size() == 5000) { // create tasks with bunch of 5000 records
                    MyParallelTask task = new MyParallelTask (new ArrayList<>(records),...);
                    tasks.add(task);
                    records.clear();
            }
      }

      if(!records.isEmpty()) { // create another task if some more records pending
            MyParallelTask task = new MyParallelTask (new ArrayList<>(records),...);
            tasks.add(task);
            records.clear();
       }

       try(ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
            List<Future<String>> shapeFilePersistFutures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
            for (Future<String> shapeFilePersistFuture : shapeFilePersistFutures) {
                 shapeFilePersistFuture.get();
            }
            executorService.shutdown();
       }
 } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw new CustomException(....);
 }

MyParallelTask takes care of processing records, like extracting geometry and persisting in database. Seems while extracting geometry, things are going wrong,specifically at follwoing code:
record.getCompoundPointBuffer().getPositions().iterator();

Error is:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newPosition < 0: (5044 < 0)
        at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createPositionException(Buffer.java:352)
        at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:327)
        at java.base/java.nio.IntBuffer.position(IntBuffer.java:1551)
        at java.base/java.nio.IntBuffer.position(IntBuffer.java:285)
        at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.CompoundVecBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.VecBufferSequence.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.VecBufferSequence.createSlice(Unknown Source)
        at gov.nasa.worldwind.util.CompoundVecBuffer.slice(Unknown Source)

I am not able to pinpoint a possibility of race condition in the code. So am not sure what is causing the issue.
